# Replenishing lives over a time period

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game in Spritekit and I want to create a way for the user's lives to replenish after 30 minutes after they lose my game.
I created an integer (called Lives) and everytime the user loses the game it subtracts 1 from the integer. Once it gets to zero the user no longer has lives.

I just dont know how to replenish the user's lives over a time period when the user no longer has lives

I was thinking of creating a wait SKAction method to create the timer but I know the skaction will cancel out when the user exits out of my game and the user will gain his/her lives back.

Does anybody know how I can effectively do this?
Is it possible to effectively do this without a server?

Comment: Use an NSTimer that fires every 30 minutes. When it fires, check to see if you should add a life.

Comment: An NSTimer will also stop running when the app is in the background or terminated. You need to periodically check the actual time and compare it against some starting time to see if 30 min has elapsed. You can store the starting time in NSUserDefaults or similar and check on app launch

Comment: @John Also note that NSTimer won't stop firing if the view/scene/node is paused.